# How to return value from async method?

Tags: asynchronous, parse-platform, return

I need to get value from asynchronous query. I tried to get my code to return it, but it still works wrong. Firstly it write in console "undefined", then it write "19" - it's correct value. So, where is an error?

My code:

```
var Back = Parse.Object.extend("Back");
var query = new Parse.Query(Back);
var LastSerial;

query.get("ghxbtU2KSl").then(function(result){
    LastSerial=result.get("SerialNumber");
    console.log(LastSerial);
    return LastSerial
});

console.log(LastSerial);
```

Comment: `console.log(LastSerial)` should also in promise chain.

Comment: `console.log(LastSerial)` is performed without waiting the response of `query.get(...)` so the value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already mentioned in the comments, the query will be run asynchronously which means Lastserial will not have been assigned a value when you print it to the console.
 Everything that depends on the value of Lastserial will need be either nested inside the callback or you may take a look at promises in series [promises in parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises) 
 I edited your example to visualize what this means:

```
var Back = Parse.Object.extend("Back");
var query = new Parse.Query(Back);
var LastSerial;

query.get("ghxbtU2KSl").then(function(result){
    //async 
    LastSerial=result.get("SerialNumber");
    //this will print the value correctly  
    console.log(LastSerial);
    return LastSerial
});

//this will be run without waiting for the query to finish, hence print undefined
console.log(LastSerial);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "return" a value from a .then clause in a Promise. The then clause will run sometime in the future after the code that created it has already exited. The way to handle this is call a function from the then clause that processes the returned data.

Alternatively, you can "chain" your Promises.

```
var Back = Parse.Object.extend("Back");
var query = new Parse.Query(Back);
var LastSerial;
var p0;
var p1;

p0 = query.get("ghxbtU2KSl");
p1 = p0.then(function(result){
    //async 
    LastSerial=result.get("SerialNumber");
    //this will print the value correctly  
    console.log(LastSerial);
    return LastSerial
});

p1.then(function(result){
    // Do stuff with result, which is LastSerial 
    console.log(result);
    return 0
});

//this will be run without waiting for the query to finish, hence print undefined
console.log(LastSerial);
```